# WinPdb Error (Debugging Django) :CTimeoutHTTP instance has no attribute 'getresponse'

Tags: django, winpdb

I am trying to learn winpdb to debug django scripts. I have a *very* simply django web site that runs find if I start it from the command line, but when I try to launch it from winpdb it gives me this error message:

```
RPDB2 - The Remote Python Debugger, version RPDB_2_4_6,
Copyright (C) 2005-2009 Nir Aides.
Type "help", "copyright", "license", "credits" for more information.

*** NEW: Use CTRL-N for auto completion in the following commands: launch,
*** eval and exec.
*** Password has been set to a random password.
*** Starting debuggee...
*** Command returned the following error:
*** <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, CTimeoutHTTP instance has no
*** attribute 'getresponse'.
*** Please check stderr for stack trace and report to support.
*** Failed to find script.
```

I don't even know where to start fixing this. It CTimeoutHTTP looks like an MFC thing. I installed wxpython with the ANSI version, then when it complained, I installed the unicode version (without removing the ANSI version.) That is the only unusual thing I can think of. Any help would be appreciated.

I should say, running on Windows XP.

Answer (score 11):

Fixed in Winpdb 1.4.8

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much. The rpdb2 console is... functional but not exactly ergonomic.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug with rpdb2 in Python 2.7.  Try downloading [Python 2.6](http://python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/) and running winpdb against that.  You'll need the appropriate wxPython library and you'll need to re-run:

```
python setup.py install -f
```

to install winpdb.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this exact same error.  I upgraded from Winpdb 1.4.6 to 1.4.8 as suggested by nir above and no longer see it (can't vote his answer up as I'm a new user).